# how to add label of graphs string values like first layer second layer third instead of layer numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
# prepare dataset
trainX, trainy, testX, testy = create_dataset()

# evaluate model and plot learning curve with given number of nodes
num_nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for n_nodes in num_nodes:
    # evaluate model with a given number of nodes
    history, result = evaluate_model(
        n_nodes,
        trainX,
        trainy,
        testX,
        testy,
    )

    # summarize final test set accuracy
    print('nodes=%d: %.3f' % (n_nodes, result))

    # plot learning curve
    pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label=str(n_nodes))
```

[image]

Comment: change your label when you plot.  example for the first one ```pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label="first layer" )```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], including some example data. It's not clear what you are asking entirely. Are you wanting to replace the legend text with more descriptive strings?

Comment: i want to add labels in graph like first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh in graph instead of numeric value pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label="first layer"

Comment: this code display label first layer to all the layers

Comment: i know i just give you an a example. create an list like this: ```layers = ["first layer", "second layer ", "third layer","fourth","five layer","six layer","seven layer"]``` and then ```pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label=layers )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your names ahead of time:

```py
# prepare dataset
trainX, trainy, testX, testy = create_dataset()

# evaluate model and plot learning curve with given number of nodes
num_nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
node_names = [
    "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh"
]

for name, n_nodes in zip(node_names, num_nodes):
    # evaluate model with a given number of nodes
    history, result = evaluate_model(
        n_nodes,
        trainX,
        trainy,
        testX,
        testy,
    )

    # plot learning curve
    pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label=name)
```

Comment: and i also not want to plot first two layer i.e. i want to create plot of third fourth fifth sixth and seventh layers not first and second layer

Comment: @SukhpalKaur change `num_nodes` and `node_names` to: `num_nodes = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and `node_names = ["Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh"]`